# How to add deployed components to puppeth configuration

Tags: bootnodes

Is it possible to add a bootnode (created using geth or bootnode command let's say) to an existing puppeth configuration? So that when the puppeth dashboard is created, it points to this bootnode?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as of now.

Puppeth manages all its components using docker and docker-compose, and relies on a ton of environmental variables, config values, files at specific locations, etc. within the containers themselves to permit discovering and assembling everything together easily.

It might be an interesting thought to have a functionality to specify "external" network components that are not managed, just perhaps advertised. There is no such functionality for now.

Comment: Yes it'd be great to add this functionnality. Thks for the answer